# Confusion with dynamics

Tags: composition

I'm not sure if anyone's asked these before on here but I'm trying sort some dynamics out on my composing project and I have some questions:

1) What I want to do is have a diminuendo from *ff* to *p* across 4 bars; do I use 4 separate diminuendos or just 1 across the 4 bars?

2)After the part mentioned in the previous question I want to have a sudden *sfz* on both hands (I'm using a piano btw) so do I put one *sfz* between the 2 staffs or a *sfz* for each?

3)After the *sfz*, I want to go back to *p* and crescendo across another 4 bars back into *ff* so do I put a *p* after the *sfz* and then after the crescendo (or crescendos depending on the answer to the first question) do I put *ff*?

PS: I'd ask my music teacher but I'd probably forget the questions by Monday

Comment: P.S. - show your music teacher this post on Monday!

Answer (score 1):

1) You shouldn't use multiple decrescendos so use just the one, but if that looks awkward because 4 measures is wide use staff text ***decresc.*** after the fortisimo.
2) Sforzando is an accent, not a dynamic mark, so put it on both hands' notes.
3) Yes do this. Consider using staff text ***cresc.*** instead of a 4 measure crescendo.

Comment: I've never seen two sfz markings in the same place (i.e. measure and beat) in a piano score: it's **always** been one sfz marking between staves.

Comment: @Dekkadeci It happens occasionally when the voices are doing something very different (so it wouldn’t be obvious that the sfz goes for both hands).

Comment: Helpful, maybe.  But incorrect regarding the sfz I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

One of everything, between the staves. (waffle to reach 30 characters)

[image]